# Can we give bulk url's in this code?

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-scraping, urlconnection

URL url = new URI("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/").toURL();

I want to give 100 url in this connector?

I have the code to run single home page to extract its data

I need to get more contents From several links !

Is it any way possible ?

Here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;

 import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
 import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

 public class NewClass {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org").get();
  Elements section = doc.select("section#content");
  Elements article = section.select("article");
  for (Element a : article) {
    System.out.println("Title : \n" + a.select("a").text());
    System.out.println("Article summary: \n" + a.select("div.entry-summary").text());
  }
}
```

}

I got output from this single page Now i need to get it from several pages (100+links) at once.

And to save it in a document.

Comment: you mean you want to create 100 different url obejcts ?

Comment: Please, add some details. It is not clear what do you want to do. What does it mean "send bulk" in this code?

Comment: I need to extract data from all links given to me. for ex :I want to search a query in 1000+ websites.I have all those links separately.Now I need to run and get my search at once.Is it possible?.

Comment: Still i cant find the correct solution anyone can say about it.

Comment: Why not just write a outter loop for create a connector for each iteration?